# jquery combobox behind embedded object (IE only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, combobox

In Internet Explorer, I have a jquery combobox which opens behind an embedded object (for example a pdf document). How can I make sure the combobox is always in front of the embedded object?

See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/RDd3A/258/ (updated fiddle containing my attempts to solve it)

HTML:

```
<select id="combobox">
  <option value="">Select one...</option>
  <option value="23">Really long stuff that might wrap</option>
  <option value="25">Normal Stuff</option>   
</select>
<br/>
<embed src="https://www.xs4all.nl/media/transparantie/Transparantierapport-2012.pdf"/>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#combobox").combobox();
```

(I've stripped all css)

I've already tried the following:

- Use wmode="transparant" as attribute
- Use ?wmode=transparant in the url
- Use an iframe
- Use z-index

Unfortunately, this doesn't help, the combobox is still behind the embedded document. Anyone?

Comment: What is your question exactly? You want the combobox box to appear above the embedded object?

Comment: Yes, the options of the combobox aren't visible in IE. I want them to appear above the embedded object.

Comment: Try to create a new iframe such as <iframe src="about:blank" class="mask" /> that you will put it between the other iframe and your UL element. The challenge is then to position that mask exactly under the UL, with the right width and height.

Comment: See proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/RDd3A/261/. You must now write code that dynamically creates and positions that mask exactly under the UL, with the right width and height. More a job for the developer of the "combobox" plugin if you want my opinion

Comment: Gyum, thank you for this solution, it works correct. (unfortunately it is a quite heavy solution). I will wait a few days to see if there might be another solution, otherwise I'll award you the bounty (I think you'll have to create an answer for that)

Comment: Yes that's heavy I know... But I do not think you can get away any other way. If you spy the web browser window using a tool such as Spy++, you will see that the iframe has got his own Window, and is therefore on top of everything HTML object. The only way to fight it is to mask it using another iframe.
I have seen other workarounds being used, such as hiding the content of the iframe when having to display something on top (eg: set visibility to hidden).
As per posting a complete answer, I don't think I'm familiar enough with jquery and the combobox to do so. Nevermind the bounty.

Comment: Well, it might not be a complete answer, but it is a working solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a known **IE** issue, I did an investigation some time ago and the only way I know is already mentioned by @Gyum Fox - another 'mask' `iframe`. However you don't have to put an iframe "between" the elements - you can put absolutely positioned `iframe` inside corresponding element with **100%** **height** and **width**.
CSS of an iframe to be placed inside of the element:

```
iframe.ie-fix {
   position: absolute;
   border: none;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

The problem that **jQuery** constructs menu content dynamically, so we need to handle some events to insert the mask. This simple code adds mask to all menus on the page. Not a complete solution, however shows the approach:

```
$('.ui-button').click(function() {
     $('.ui-menu').append("<iframe class='ie-fix' src='about:blank'></iframe>" ); 
});
```

Ideally we need to update only corresponding menu, butI need to dig deeper into jQuery's sources to accomplish that, will try to address later.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RDd3A/270) with complete example

Comment: possibly you need to add some check if this `ie-fix` already exists in `ui-menu` cause that code adds new `iframe` every time you click

Answer (score 0):

This is an IE issue. I had a similar problem using a combobox inside a modal dialog in JQuery UI. The combobox would work fine in Chrome or Firefox. The only way I found to resolve that issue is to place it inside an `iframe`. I worked for me in the modal dialog.

IE and JQuery seem to work fine together as long as you don't do anything too fancy. I also tried placing a s select box in a modal dialog and it didn't work either. I avoid using two JQuery UI elements when they must be nested.

Since udalmik answered first, you should use his implementation.