# Sub-menu is hidden behind PDF type object ( issue in Internet explorer)

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a object type tag in the page, which is used to show a pdf file.
Everything is working fine, but in Internet Explorer my sub-menu is getting hidden behind the object tag.

```
var objectTag = $('<object></object>')
.attr({ data: sourceURL + '#nameddest=self&page=1&view=FitV'
 || '', type: mimeType || '' })
.css({ width: '100%', height: '100%', zindex:'1' });
```

Please find red highlighted area.
[image: Please find red highlighted area.]

I have tried many things. Please don't suggest z-index thing.

Comment: See the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911428/z-index-does-not-work-in-ie7-ie8-with-pdf-in-iframe. You can solve your problem by addding an iframe between the menu and the pdf

Comment: I have already checked it. No use.

Comment: Show us some code for menu and complete page html/ structure. Its impossible to guess the exact error with this object tag.

Comment: @Era please you find the code in the below link. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655470/sub-menu-going-behind-the-bol-using-html-object

I hope this may help to figure out the issue. You can copy the code and save in the file as html and open that html in the Internet Explorer. And just to see the difference in the submenu(step2), please open the same file in the other browser link chrome.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/25760079/54680. Which version(s) of Internet Explorer are you experiencing this issue with?

Comment: Thanks it is bit similar.
And I can't use iframe for my web app.

Comment: Why can't we suggest z-index.  What is the positioning of the object set to?  Absolute or relative? Also, is your navigation's z-index set and position set?

Comment: Oh and your .css({zindex:'1'}) should be 'z-index': '1'

Comment: No this code is okay!! its not an issue with z-index.

Comment: What version of IE and Adobe Reader are you using?

Comment: Internet Explorer 11 and Adobe reader 11

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there isn't any pure answer to your question, but you can always add `<br><br><br>` before the PDF so that the PDF goes further down and doesn't touch the sub-menu.

Comment: Correct these are work arounds. Things like these I have already tried. But I am looking for a proper solution.

Comment: I don't think that there is any proper solution: IE opens PDF documents with Adobe Reader and so the PDF is like another window except that it isn't shown in the task bar and doesn't have any title bar, so a proper solution would be the same thing as mixing the content of two windows in two different programs, which is impossible. In that sense, IE is different from other browsers like Chrome which have built-in PDF viewers.