# Sub menu going behind the PDF using HTML OBJECT Only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

when i am implementing PDFs bol object in my webpage using simple html object, it is displaying well in both chrome and Explorer( IE 11). The main problem is the sub menu's of main navigation(sub menu) is going behind of PDFs viewer in Explorer (IE) . And one more thing all the position attributes and z-index values are fine . This is a problem with object . please show me solution. I am not able to create fiddle for this. for more details see my below code and run in your Internet Explorer browser and **hover the "step 2"** navigation menu. `enter code here`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 body{margin:0 auto;width:500px;}
 header{height:60px;background:#ccc;}
 ul#mainnav{list-style:none;display:block;position:relative;z-index:1000;}
 ul#mainnav li{float:left;width:80px;}
 ul#mainnav li#step2 ul#submenu{display:none;list-style:none;position:absolute;z-index:99;margin-left:-40px;margin-top:5px;}
 ul#mainnav li#step2:hover ul#submenu{display:block;}
 ul#mainnav li#step2 ul#submenu li{float:none;height:30px;border-bottom:1px solid #fff;background:#000;color:#fff;display:block;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
    <ul id="mainnav">
      <li>step1</li>
      <li id="step2">step2
        <ul id="submenu">
            <li>step2 1</li>
            <li>step2 2</li>
            <li>step2 3</li>
            <li>step2 4</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>step3</li>
      <li>step4</li>
      <li>step5</li>
      <li style="clear:both;"></li>
    </ul>
    </header>
    <div style="width:300px;height:400px;position:relative;border:2px sild #fff;float:left;">
    <object data="http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf" style="width:94%;height:94%;position:absolute;z-index:0;padding:5px;"  type="application/pdf" wmode="transparent" >
     <param name="wMode" value="transparent"/>
    </object>
    </div>
    </body>


</html>
```

In Internet explorer click **Allow blocked Content** button, then only you can see PDF in explorer.

This is not duplicate to any question . I don't want to use any Iframe and embed elements. Through **object** only I need this. Please suggest me.

Comment: Direct copy the above code and paste in your editor , save and run in Internet Explorer and chrome observe what happened.

Comment: That's a feature in IE, there's nothing you can do with `z-index` or any other things to bring the page in front of an object.

Comment: @Teemu , thanks for your response.I know this is IE feature. Please suggest me how to report this problem to Microsoft.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: Hi your question is not duplicate of my question .My question is only using object pdf , not embed and iframe. I want only using object tag.