# Using 3D transform flip is not working in IE11 (mine is different)

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I investigate on CSS3 3d transform and finally I got some code for CSS3 3d flip action. So it's working fine in all browsers except **Internet Explorer (IE11)**.
So I investigated on this issue in stackoverflow.com. I got some solutions but unfortunately those are not useful for me. So please kindly have a look at my jsfiddle link and provide some solution for this.

**CODE:**

```js
$('#one').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $("#card").addClass("flipped");
            $(".back #append").append("<p>First one</p>")
        }
    });
$('#two').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $("#card").addClass("flipped");
            $(".back #append").append("<p>second one</p>")
        }
    });
$('#three').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $("#card").addClass("flipped");
            $(".back #append").append("<p>third one</p>")
        }
    });
$('#close').click(function() {
    $("#card").removeClass("flipped");
});
```

```css
.container { 
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  -ms-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}
#card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
#card figure {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;  
}
#card .front {
  background: red;
}
#card .back {
  background: blue;
    -ms-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
#card.flipped {
  -ms-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
#close{
    position:absolute;bottom:0px;right:0px;color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
  <div id="card">
    <figure class="front">
        <input type="checkbox" id="one"/>one<br></br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="two"/>two<br></br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="three"/>three<br></br>
      </figure>
    <figure class="back">
        <div id="append"></div>
        <div id="close"><button>close</button></div>
    </figure>
  </div>
</section>
```

for more details see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/Rayudu/jy0z8dy1/

*kindly click on check box then flip will happen and click on close button to remove flip.*

Comment: Did that answer help solve your problem mate? If yes, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the hollow tick mark. Else, please clarify more on what problems you are facing.

Comment: @Harry , Sorry for late. Thanks a lot. your answer is exact good for my query. it's good.

Comment: @Harry, I have one doubt . previously i posted one question on stack overflow. No one provide good for me. can u look at my link please do needful.  "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655470/sub-menu-going-behind-the-pdf-using-html-object-only?noredirect=1#comment43754680_27655470"

Comment: That question has been marked as a duplicate mate. So wouldn't be able to add any answers to that one :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had run into the same problem earlier and found that making the back-face visible in the flipped state solves it. So for your case, adding the below lines should fix the issue in IE11 (and also IE10).

```
#card.flipped figure{
  backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

```js
$('#one').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#card").addClass("flipped");
    $(".back #append").append("<p>First one</p>")
  }
});
$('#two').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#card").addClass("flipped");
    $(".back #append").append("<p>second one</p>")
  }
});
$('#three').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#card").addClass("flipped");
    $(".back #append").append("<p>third one</p>")
  }
});
$('#close').click(function() {
  $("#card").removeClass("flipped");
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  -ms-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}
#card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
#card figure {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#card .front {
  background: red;
}
#card .back {
  background: blue;
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
#card.flipped {
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
#card.flipped figure {
  backface-visibility: visible;
}
#close {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
  <div id="card">
    <figure class="front">
      <input type="checkbox" id="one" />one
      <br></br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="two" />two
      <br></br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="three" />three
      <br></br>
    </figure>
    <figure class="back">
      <div id="append"></div>
      <div id="close">
        <button>close</button>
      </div>
    </figure>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

**Note:** Addition of the above property setting seems to be causing some flickers in Google Chrome and that could be overcome by over-riding the setting for GC alone (like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/v87462tt/) kindly contributed by [web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki)). Generally it is not a good approach to add prefixed versions after the un-prefixed (standard) property, but it is not much of an issue here as we are over-riding specifically for Chrome.

Comment: sorry for the late . your answer is exact useful for me. it's great. Thanks and BestRegards.

Comment: @Rayudu: No worries mate. Glad to be of help :)