# CSS flip animation compatibility issues with IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm sure this question has been answered before but I'm giving it a shot nonetheless. This is my first experiment with CSS animations and low and behold, they don't work in IE, but do in FF and Chrome. I've popped the site up [here](http://www.chriswickham.co.uk/ward4) but as you can see, IE just shows the reverse of the 'front' div, rather than the 'back' div.

Here is the relevant code - any help will be appreciated! I apologise for its inelegance.

CSS

```
.tileContent{
            position: absolute;
            margin: auto;
            top: 30%;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            color: #FFF;
            font-family: content;
            font-size:14px;
        }   
        .container{
            width: 33%;
            height: auto;
            float: left;
            background:#000;
            position:relative;
            perspective:1000;
        }
        .container.flip .about, .container.flip .gigs, .container.flip .media{
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }
        .front{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            z-index: 2;
            background: #9E9E81;
            text-align: center;
            border: solid #000 thick;
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        }
        .back{
            z-index: 1;
            background: #000;
            color:#FFF;
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            width: 100%;
            height:0px;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        .front,.back{
            position: absolute;
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
        }
        .about, .gigs, .media{
            width:100%;
            height:300px;
            position: relative;
            -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
            -moz-transition: 0.6s;
            transition: 0.6s;
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            font-family: content;
            font-size:14px;
            line-height:2;
        }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            var aboutActive = false;
            var gigsActive = false;
            var mediaActive = false;

            $(".aboutHead").click(function(){
            if(aboutActive==false){
                $(".about").children(".back").css("height","auto");
                $(".about").children(".back").css("overflow","visible");
                $('#left').toggleClass('flip');
                aboutActive=true;
            }else{
                $('#left').toggleClass('flip');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".about").children(".back").css("height","0px");
                    $(".about").children(".back").css("overflow","hidden");
                    },500);
                aboutActive=false;
                }
            });

            $(".gigsHead").click(function(){
            if(gigsActive==false){
                $(".gigs").children(".back").css("height","auto");
                $(".gigs").children(".back").css("overflow","visible");
                $('#middle').toggleClass('flip');
                gigsActive=true;
            }else{
                $('#middle').toggleClass('flip');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".gigs").children(".back").css("height","0px");
                    $(".gigs").children(".back").css("overflow","hidden");
                    },500);
                gigsActive=false;
                }
            });

            $(".mediaHead").click(function(){
            if(mediaActive==false){
                $(".media").children(".back").css("height","auto");
                $(".media").children(".back").css("overflow","visible");
                $('#right').toggleClass('flip');
                mediaActive=true;
            }else{
                $('#right').toggleClass('flip');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".media").children(".back").css("height","0px");
                    $(".media").children(".back").css("overflow","hidden");
                    },500);
                mediaActive=false;
                }
            });

        });
```

HTML (just the left hand panel)

```
<div class="container" id="left">
        <div class="about">
            <div class="front" id="aboutFront">
                <div class="tileContent">
                    <img class="aboutHead" src="about.png" width="30%" />
                    <p>Read more about the band<br /> and its members</p>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <img style="position:relative;padding: 10px 0 0 10px" class="aboutHead" src="about.png" width="20%"/>
                <p>Ward 4 is a Buckinghamshire-based 5-piece band consisting of drummer/singer John, frontman Marty G, guitarists Richard and Phil, and bassist Glen. They united in the late 1990s under one love; rock n' roll. The band is famous for their renditions of rhythm n' blues hits, country ballads and 60's popular music. While Ward 4 is a quintet, the original line-up consisted of four members; John, who also took on lead vocal duty, Richard, Phil and Glen. After the later addition of the charismatic 'Marty Gee', the band saw no reason to change the name which had already gained them a reputation of a fantastic live act, and thus remained Ward 4, rather than 5! </p>
                <p>Ward 4's main frontman, Marty G lives and breathes 50's rock and roll; immediately evident in his pop attire, slicked-back hair and sharp voice. There is no doubt that his later addition was the final piece of the band's jigsaw, bringing the extra depth to their live sound they had spent so long searching for. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sounds similar to [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917557/using-3d-transform-flip-is-not-working-in-ie11-mine-is-different/28922824#28922824).

Comment: It looks similar, but I'm struggling to apply it to my own work :/

Comment: I don't have access to a machine with IE10/11 right now, but try with `.container.flip .about > div{backface-visibility: visible;}`.

Comment: Seems to have worked, but its placed behind the flipped 'front' div. I suppose I'll just have to switch the z-index?

Comment: I think you may not even need the `z-index` in the first place mate. Seems to work fine on my old chrome even without it.

Comment: Works pretty well now - the 'back' panel appears before the flip occurs but I'll take what I can get right now. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Ok, I will check that and ping you when I find time. For now, I am marking it as a dupe because repeating the same answer here wouldn't be correct. I hope you don't have any concerns.

Comment: Nah that's fine. It's also introduced the same problem in FF :(